# Remove duplicates from a sorted array

Tags: c++, performance, programming-challenge, vectors

I have solved the [LeetCode Remove Duplicates From Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/) problem:

> Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates in place such that each element appear only once and return the new length. It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the new length.

I was able to come up with a approach but only when I submitted this solution and got it accepted I found that my solution ranked somewhere around 60%, ranked by run-time. i.e) My solution was only faster that 40% of other contestants solution for the same language.

```
  int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
    if (nums.size() == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    auto start = nums.begin(), end = nums.end();
    int last_value = *(nums.end() - 1);
    for (auto it = nums.begin(); it != end;)
    {
        int find_value = *it;
        auto upper = upper_bound(start, end, find_value); //Find the last occurring index of this number 
        iter_swap(start, it);
        ++start;
        if ((upper != end) || ((upper == end) && (find_value == last_value)))
        {
            it = upper;
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    return distance(nums.begin(), start);
}
```

Could you please suggest any performance improvements to this code. And also please go easy on the naming convention and code formatting. This was written for a programming challenge :)

### Edit.

The worst case time complexity i believe is `O(n Log n)` which happens when the entire array is unique. And the best case run time should be `O(log n)` when the entire array contains duplicates.

Comment: İf it ran faster than others, why are you looking for further improvements?

Comment: @CEGRD Because some other solutions were faster, which indicates that there is room for improvement.

Comment: What do you think is the time complexity of your solution?  Can you think of a different algorithm with better time complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many special cases.

Why do you care about what the `last_value` is?  Just checking `it != end` should be sufficient to terminate the loop.

Then, when you no longer need `last_value = *(nums.end() - 1)`, you can also get rid of the `nums.size() == 0` special case.

You have iterators `it` and `start`.  `start` is a rather confusing name, since it refers to an iterator that moves along.  You could call them `src` and `dest`, or `in` and `out`, or `fast` and `slow`.  I'm going with `rabbit` and `turtle`.

Swapping with `iter_swap()` isn't necessary; just a simple assignment will do.

```
int removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator rabbit, turtle, end = nums.end();
    for ( rabbit = turtle = nums.begin();
          rabbit != end;
          rabbit = std::upper_bound(rabbit, end, *turtle), turtle++ ) {
        *turtle = *rabbit;
    }
    return std::distance(nums.begin(), turtle);
}
```

I have a suspicion that much of the time, the very next element is already going to be different.  It might be worth it to do a quick peek at the next element before going through the trouble of launching a binary search.

Comment: `rabbit = std::upper_bound(rabbit, end, *turtle), turtle++` Are you serious?

Comment: @vnp Sorry, was that too long? Would you have preferred `rabbit = std::upper_bound(rabbit, end, *turtle++)`?

Comment: No. `,` is a comma operator. It evaluates left to right and produces a rightmost expression. Your continuation amounts to `rabbit = turtle++`, and I am sure it is not what you've meant.

Comment: @vnp The comma has lowest precedence. It's `rabbit = std::upper_bound(…)`, followed by `turtle++`.

Comment: Lower precedence than what? `rabbit = x, y;` it is. Try a debugger if you don't trust the Standard.

Comment: @vnp [The assignment operator (precedence level 15) binds more tightly than the comma (precedence level 16).](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `rabbit = x, y` would assign `rabbit = x`, then the whole expression has the value `y`.

Comment: You solution looks a lot cleaner and ran all the test cases in 29ms while mine took 33ms.

Comment: Consider accepting @miscco's answer instead. It's a better solution in every way.

Answer (score 5):

So the simplest solutions is to use the available stl function. However there is obviously less to learn there.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    nums.erase(std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()), nums.end()); ;
    return nums.size();
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the most c++ way to do this.  It also makes use of the erase-remove idom.  std::unique moves the duplicates to the end of the list and returns a new "end" iterator.  Erase cleans those out.  Note the size of the container remains the same.

Comment: Note that `.erase()` is not strictly required in this problem statement. `std::unique()` would do a linear scan.

Comment: @200_success This is correct, however It seems bad practice, to keep memory around, that is possibly undefined.

Comment: A single line solution that runs in just 25ms . Brilliant :)